# mi app copila y se abre en el emulador de android studio pero no conecta con el servidor

Tags: android-studio, angular, ionic, capacitor

Hola buenas tengo una app creada en ionic y cuando realizo un ionic serve funciona perfectamente pero cuando abro en android studio puedo me compila y se abre sin errores en el emulador y la app se ve bien pero no accede a la base de datos o al servidor y no entiendo donde puedo ver que problema tiene o en que archivo se configura la conexión en android studio la app se levanta con el emulador pero al intentar registrar el usuario me envía error en el servidor como si no conectara a la base de datos .

Comment: Es una api? Se conecta sobre https?. Tengo entendido que android requiere https para permitir una conexión. Que Error te envía? Puedes poner toda esa información y editar la pregunta para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Hola. considera agrega màs informaciòn, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Hola lo que sucede es que el emulador de android es como una maquina virtual que tiene su propia red con segmentos de red, tu maquina es localhost y usa 127.0.0.1 que no es accesible desde el emulador de android. En algún momento presente este problema y mi solucin fue correr la api en un servidor de internet con una url real, si mal no recuerdo use awardspace (mi api era en php), cuando compilaba al emulador, al estar conectado a internet podia emular de manera real el comportamiento de la aplicación, con datos "reales" o un comportamiento "real" consumiendo datos desde una api.